# In C# Webdriver, I want to Click on one link from many which are available on web page

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to Click on one link from many which are available on web page and I had written one code where I used switch case which is given below. So can any one tell me, can we use enum or any other way to click on particular link. And in return it will give Pageobject.

The code which I am using with switch case with two links,

```
public Object SelectMenu(string menuName)
{

    Object result = null;

    IWebElement menuTemp = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//a[contains(text(),'" + menuName + "')]"));

    if (menuTemp.Enabled)
    {
        menuTemp.Click();
        if (menu.ToUpper() == "COUNTRY")
        {
            result = new CountryPage(driver).Load();
        }

        else if (menu.ToUpper() == "PARTNER")
        {
            result = new PartnerPage(driver).Load();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this ?

```
string  menu = "country";

        switch (menu.ToUpper())
        {
            case "COUNTRY":
                result = new CountryPage(driver).Load();
                break;
            case "PARTNER":
                result = new PartnerPage(driver).Load();
                break;                
        }
```

Comment: see my code , menuTemp is link and if der r 30 link , so i have to write 30 cases and after click on code we will get back in return on page which you written in ur code as well , is der anythig which can reduce dis code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to type out the classes that you expect to instantiate but the naming of the menuitems and your ...Page class is consistent you can lookup your Page types with reflection and bind to the constructor and Load method. An example of such approach is this:

```
var menu = "Country";
var pageClass = (from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from pageType in asm.GetTypes()
            let ctor = pageType.GetConstructor(new [] {typeof(IWebDriver)})
            let load = pageType.GetMethod("Load", Type.EmptyTypes)
            where pageType.Name.EndsWith("Page")
            && pageType.Name.StartsWith(menu, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            && ctor != null
            && load != null
            select new { Constructor = ctor, Load = load}).Single();

 var page = pageClass.Constructor.Invoke(new []{webdriver});
 var result = pageClass.Load.Invoke(page, null);
 // result has now your CountryPage instance
```

How does this work:

By calling [GetAssemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx) all assemblies in the process can be iterated and calling GetTypes returns all public types.
You require that your Page classes accept the IWebDriver in the constructor, so each type is interrogated for that one with the [GetConstructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx) call. A demand is done with [GetMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx) for the Load requirement.
The last thing to do is checking if the name of the type matches the convention of ending with Page and starting with the menuname.
In the final step a Single (and nothing more) item is returned.
From that result we can create the type by calling invoke and subsequently the [invoke method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) for the Load member.
That final result is returned.

Notice that if you create a type CountryCityPage you'll find two types. I leave it as an exercise for the reader to come up with a solution for that